# Django Unittesting adding a variable to the session

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, session

In my unittest I need to add a variable to the session, because that variable is used in the view which is being tested. The django documentation says this is possible in the following way (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/testing/#django.test.client.Client.session):

```
def test_something(self):
    session = self.client.session
    session['somekey'] = 'test'
    session.save()
```

This code example actually doesn't work, because you will get the error that a dict doesn't have a function save. I also tried various other ways to change the contents inside the session dict, but haven't found a way to change it yet. 
I know what it means, what i get back is a dict object so it doesnt have the save function. But the session dict also doesn't update when adding keys.

The documentation statues when using self.client.session it should return a SessionStore object instead of a dictionary.

Comment: Are you using `unittest` or `django.utils.unittest`?

Comment: Why do you need to save it? Where are you checking the session elsewhere?

Comment: Just as a wild guess, try removing the ```session.save()``` line and see if it works.  My reading of the source code for django.test.client.Client shows that the session attribute is just the session object straight out of the engine.  It should be saved automatically by the the Session middleware.

Comment: I tried that, thats also what i thought after debugging and finding out that it was just a dict. Will have another try maybe i didnt do it right.

Comment: @Elf Sternberg: It doesn't work, just tried it again. `self.client.session['user_id'] = self.user.id`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems right now there is a bug in Django, so it doesn't work for unauthenticated users to change the session. This is the corresponding ticket: https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/11475 .

A work around is to create a dummy view in which the session variables are set and calling that view with the Client.get('url_of_dummy_view').

Answer (score 0):

The ticket referenced by @Sam Stoelinga has been closed as a duplicate. The corresponding ticket can be found [here](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/10899).

To save session data you will have to use an authenticated user. I found a solution [here](http://www.gregaker.net/2011/aug/29/testing-django-views-that-rely-on-session-variables/).

```
class BlogAdminTestCase(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        # Setup Test User
        User.objects.create_user(
            username='foo',
            password='bar'
        )

        # Must login to modify session variables
        self.client.login(username='foo', password='bar')

        s = self.client.session
        s['my_session_variable'] = 'Yay!'
        s.save()
```